# Use case of !default in variable in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

In SCSS variable what is the significance of !default

```
$gutter:1rem !default;
$enable-grid:true !default;
$grid-columns:12 !default;
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the first bit states search and research - type your title into google and you will find plenty of sites telling you what it is for

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is easily found with a bit of effort

Comment: @Pete - for example here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sass-default

Answer (score 0):

it assigned to a variable value, if the value of variable is already assigned then it will take the old value (default value) or if not assigned already than it take new value at which **!default** has been written.